# How to return all docs matching value in the array of one of the field : mongodb aggration

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have stored the collection as give below

```
  .....
   name : "product name",
  "productCategories": [
    "5f44f61fd4051ef8fa104537",
    "5f44e28dd4051ef8fa1044ef",
    "5f460caf21262a1ce99934e4"
  ],
....
```

I am trying to query aggregate in mongodb ( mongoose but i am not able match against value in

> prodcutCategories

var aggregate = this.productModel.aggregate([{ $match:{  }}])

I tried  all nothing working for simple solution , can any body help me

update:

var aggregate = this.productModel.aggregate([{$match:{productCategories :new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args._id)}}])

solved my issues ..

Comment: just try, `var aggregate = this.productModel.aggregate([{ $match:{productCategories: "5f44e28dd4051ef8fa1044ef" }}])`  and i think you did spelling mistake in `prodcutCategories` it should be `productCategories`

Comment: @turivishal  No i am not able to get result .. its showing empty array

Comment: I think query is good, you need to check your implementation. and check database connection and collection name. and write query inside `async` function and put `await` before query.

Comment: @turivishal yes .. Query what you suggested in  Correct i was storing it as Object ID so  I Tried with     new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args._id) .Its Working .  thanks for your suggestion

Comment: good, you can remove  this question if you want because its just you missed type conversion,